# Can't download apps through the software center

Tags: apt, software-center, software-installation, dpkg

I'm new to ubuntu , I'm using the latest version. I've been trying to download apps from the software center but I keep getting this error notification(below). Can anybody tell me how to fix this please.

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: error processing package tzdata (--configure):
 package tzdata is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tzdata
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tz:
 python-tz depends on tzdata; however:
 Package tzdata is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package python-tz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-matplotlib:
```

Comment: First try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Thanks guys, All I needed to do is configure tzdata package.